# Integrate SVGs in Odoo

Tags: html, xml, svg, odoo

I am trying to integrate SVGs into my odoo website, which I've built using the builder-module. It is possible to integrate simple inline svgs, like:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

However, if I try to integrate inkscape generated SVGs, odoo doesn't save them or just crashes.

Any ideas or suggestions on this?

Comment: Simplify the inkscape image till you figure out what causes the crash then report it with your testcase to Odoo.

Comment: thanks for your input Robert, works now! For noobs it is to note that inkscape has its own .svg file, where it adds all kind of stuff to the source code. Somehow, odoo doesn't like that.

Answer (score 0):

Until now **odoo** does not support **svg** to be loaded in qweb templates

Answer (score 0):

You can write your svg in its own file : your_svg_file.svg and load it this way in your_module/templates/template.xml of your custom module named "your_module":

```xml
<template id="custom_accordion" name="Custom Accordion">
    <section class="container gp_accordions" >
        <div class="row colfixed mb-5">
           <div class="col-lg-12 s_title">
              <h2 class="landing">Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
                    ...
                    ...
               <div class="ac_icon">
                 <div class="ac_lns">
 <img src="/your_module/static/src/img/snippets/structure/your_svg_file.svg"/>
                   </div>
```